# One element set for generating an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I wish to solve the following two questions:

> (a)  Give a one-element generating set for the idealI of $\mathbb Z$ given by I= (14,49).

**I solved this problem as  follows:**

Observe that this ideal must have the form $\{ 18x+49y | x,y \in \mathbb Z \}$
Now since $\gcd(14,49)=7$, we know all multiples of $14$ and $49$ are multiples of $7$, therefore contained in $7 \mathbb Z$. Similarly, we can write:
$$14x'+ 49 y'=7 $$
by the extended Euclidean algorithm, therefore we know that we can generate all of $ 7 \mathbb Z$ in this fashion. We conclude $I=(\{7\})$.

> (b)  Give a one-element generating set for the ideal I of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ given by $I= (8 +\sqrt3,122).$

I do not know how to tackle this problem. Can anyone provide a hint? I do not see any similarities with (a)..

Comment: Both rings are Euclidean domains.

Comment: In the first case, I believe you want $I=(7).$

Comment: For (b), note that $122$ is a multiple of $8+\sqrt{3}.$

Comment: Hint:  $2(8+\sqrt3)(8-\sqrt3)=2(64-3)=122$

Comment: those are good hints

Comment: That essentially means we do not need $122$, because we can generate it with the other element.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $122$ is a multiple of the other element: $4(8 + \sqrt 3)(8 - \sqrt{3})=122$. Therefore $122$ is a redundant element, we can leave it out.